# Passing a 2d array and using recursion error

Tags: arrays, recursion, methods, 2d

I am doing an assignment and have trouble getting the code compiled. The code must have recursion. The idea is to pass a 2d array sequentially - row by row, column by column and to get a private helper method to match cases and return the result.

I have tried looking at different solutions and everything seems in order, however I get an error:

```
required: int
found: int[][]
```

I am passing an array, int row and int column to a method that should be accepting exactly those three. 
Take a look:

```
public static int [][] calculateProximity ( boolean [][] mineField ) 
{
  int [][] proximityField = new int [mineField.length][mineField[0].length];

  for (int row = 0; row < mineField.length; row++) {
    for (int column=0; column <mineField[row].length; column++) {
      proximityField [row][column] = calculateProximity (mineField, row, column);
    }
  }

  return proximityField;  
}


private static int [][] calculateProximity (boolean [][] mineField,
  int row, int column)
  {
    int [][] proximityField;

    if (row >= mineField.length || column >= mineField[row].length){
      return proximityField=0;
    }
    else if (mineField [row][column]= true){
      proximityField[row][column]=1;
      return proximityField;
    }
    else
    {
      proximityField[row][column]=0;
    }

    return proximityField;
}
```

By the way, calculateProximity main method is to return an int 2d array, but it is given a boolean 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

`return proximityField=0;`, is incorrect. Here, you are returning the result of `proximityfield=0`. This is going to be a single integer, the value 0. When you assign a variable, the return value is the value you assigned to the variable. You should probably return `null` instead.

Comment: I need to create an int array in one method and pass it to the other method. Cant leave null. How would I change the code to accomplish that?

Comment: You can initialize all the slots in the array to 0 using a double for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Never use loops while performing recursion. I hope this code gives you some idea:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int i=0,j=0,k=0,flag=0;
int function_Matrix(int arr[][4],int i,int j)
{
    if(j==4||i==3)
        return 1;

        if(flag==0)
        {
            printf("\t%d",arr[i][j]);
        }
    function_Matrix(arr,i,j+=1);
    printf("\n");
    function_Matrix(arr,i+=1,j=0);
    flag=1;
}
int main()
{
    int x;
    int arr[][4]={{1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {9,7,6,5}};
    function_Matrix(arr,0,0);
}
```